# Asymptotics of the solution of $G_n(t) = \text{const}$, where $G_n(t) = e^t (1 + r^{-1}(G_{n-1}(t) - 1))^{r}$.

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

Consider a sequence of functions $(G_n(t))$ on $\Bbb{R}$ that satisfies the recurrence relation

$$ G_0(t) = e^t, \qquad G_n(t) = e^t \left( 1 + \frac{G_{s-1}(t) - 1}{r} \right)^{r}. $$

for some absolute constant $r > 1$. (Or you can assume that $r = 2, 3, \cdots$ since I am essentially only interested in such $r$'s.) Fix any constant $a > 1$. I am interested in the behavior of $(t_n)$, where it is defined as the unique solution of

$$ G_n(t_n) = a, \quad t_n > 0. $$

Then my question is as follows:

> **Q.** What is an asymptotics of $t_n$ as $n \to \infty$?

For my purpose, an ideal situation would be that $(t_n)$ has a asymptotics of the form $t_n \sim \alpha \log n / n^2$, but even an asymptotics of the form $t_n \geq \alpha \log n / n^2$ would be nice. Here are some observations on $G_n$ and $t_n$:

1. For any $t \geq 0$ we can inductively check that
   $$ \exp\{(n+1)t\} \leq G_n(t) \leq \exp \Big\{ \tfrac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1} t \Big\}. $$
   Moreover, these bounds are not arbitrary, in the sense that for each $n \geq 0$ we have $t^{-1}\log G_n(t) \to n+1$ as $t \to 0^+$ and $t^{-1} \log G_n(t) \to (r^{n+1} - 1)/(r-1)$ as $t \to \infty$.
2. Using a very indirect method, I can prove that $1 \leq G_n(\epsilon n^{-2}) \leq 1 + Cn^{-1}$ holds for some $\epsilon > 0$ and $C > 0$. This implies that $(t_n)$ does not decay faster than $n^{-2}$.
3. Aagain, using a very indirect heuristics, I suspect that $t_n \leq C \log n / n^2$.

*Remark.* It is good to read **@Did**'s comment for a probabilistic background of the quantity $G_n(t)$.

Comment: You might have mentioned that $G_n(t)=E(e^{tZ_n})$ where $(Z_n)$ is a critical Galton-Watson process starting from $Z_0=1$ with binomial $(r,1/r)$ reproducing distribution.

Comment: @Did, Yes, this problem came from the critical percolation on a variant of $(r+1)$-regular tree. I decided not to describe the setting since I wanted to see if this can be solved purely analytically, but yes, you are right. Thank you for pointing out that relation, and any form of help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, $Z_n$ is the population of the $n$ first generations.

Comment: Let $A_n=Z_n>0$: $P(A_n)\sim \frac 2 {n\sigma^2}$, $E(Z_n|A_n)\sim \frac{n\sigma^2}2$. Contributions from $A_n^c$ are negligible, hence by Jensen's and $(Z_i|A_n)\ge_{st} (Z_i|A_i)$ (for $i\le n$) we get $$\log(E(e^{tT_n}))\gtrsim \log{}\frac 2{n\sigma^2}+\frac {n^2\sigma^2}{4}t$$ and $3$ follows. Lower bound is harder - $var(Z_n|A_n)\sim \left(\frac {n\sigma^2}{2}\right)^2$, $var(T_n|A_n)\sim \frac{n^4\sigma^4}{2}$ and $n^{-1}Z_n|A_n\overset{d}\to \exp(\frac{2}{\sigma^2})$ which suggests $t_n=\Theta(\frac {\log n}{n^2})$ but I see no quick way to control the MGF/tails/higher moments.

Comment: Here is an order-of ($\Theta$) argument  for why $f_n=n^2t_n=O(1)$ through Taylor expansion of $g(x)=xe^{tx}$. Assume $f_n=\Omega(1)$ as you have mentioned and $O(\log n)$ as I have shown:

$$G'_n(t_n)\approx\frac 1 n E(T_ne^{t_nT_n}|Z_n>0)\approx\frac 1 n n^2e^{f_n}(1+\frac 1 2t_n(2+f_n)n^4)\approx n^3e^{f_n}f_n^2$$ On the other hand, $G_n(t_n)-G_n(t_{n+1})=\Theta(1)$ and $\Delta t_n=\Theta(\frac {f_n}{n^3})$ which yields $f_n=\Theta(1)$. Here I used $E(T_n|Z_n>0)=\Theta(n^2)$ and $var(T_n|Z_n>0)=\Theta(n^4)$.

Comment: @A.S. Thank you for the comment! My reasoning for 3 is essentially the same as your comment part 1: If $T_n = Z_0 + \cdots + Z_n$ denotes the population up to $n$ generation, then $\mathbf{P}(Z_n > 0) \asymp n^{-1}$ and the typical size of $T_n$ given $\{ Z_n > 0 \}$ is of order $n^2$. This suggests that for small $\epsilon > 0$, $$ n^{-1} \asymp \mathbf{P}(Z_n > 0) \lesssim \mathbf{P}(T_n > \epsilon n^2) \leq e^{-\epsilon n^2 t_n} G_n(t_n) $$  and 3 follows. To be honest, this inequality is the source of my inquiry as I want an estimate of $\mathbf{P}(T_n > \lambda n^2)$.

Comment: I included $n^2$ twice erroneously. It should read $G'_n(t_n)\approx\frac 1 n E(T_ne^{t_nT_n}|Z_n>0)\approx\frac 1 n e^{f_n}(n^2+\frac 1 2t_n(2+f_n)n^4)\approx ne^{f_n}f_n^2$  instead which again yields $f_n=O(\log n)$ but not lower bound. Estimation of $P(T_n>\lambda n^2)$ should be WAY easier than controlling moment generation function because the indicator is bounded but the exponent is not. $P(T_n>\epsilon n^2)\sim \frac C n$

Comment: You shouldn't use mgf for majorization unless you have good control over the tails or the variables in the sum are independent. We know that $\frac{T_n}n$ and $\frac {Z_n}{n}|Z_n>0$ converge in law (to gamma and exponential respectively) and $P(Z_n>0)=\Theta(n^{-1})$. It follows that $P(T_n>\epsilon n^2)=\Theta(n^{-1})$. Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @A.S. Thank you again for pointing out that issue. Would you mind if I ask you some references to the behavior of $T_n / n$ as $n \to \infty$? I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: Last slide on http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~anr-manege/agay/Vatutin/Lecture1.pdf  $T_n$ is basically Galton-Watson process with constant immigration of $1$ (the very first person added after each time shift). Because this convergence in law only, you can't use it for convergence of moments/mgf esp. since $T_n$ is basically a mixture of a $n\cdot$ gamma (w. probability $1-\frac c n$) and something of the order of $n^2$ with "subexponential-tails"  (with probability $\frac c n$). Teasing out exact order of $t_n$ would depend on close analysis of the tails of $T_n$ or $Z_n$.

Comment: How did you obtain $t_n=\Omega(n^{-2})$?

Comment: @A.S. I used what is called diagrammatic bounds to obtain $\mathbf{E}[T_n^k] \leq (2k-3)!! (Cn)^{2k-1}$ for $k \geq 1$. This follows by identifying the family tree of our Galton-Watson process as the occupied cluster $\mathcal{C}(0)$ at $0$ of the critical Bernoulli percolation on a rooted $r$-ary tree. This gives a bound $$ G_n(t) \leq 1 + \frac{C}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(Cn^2 t)^{k}}{k^{3/2}}. $$